# Retrieve string between parathesis in C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex, windows-forms-designer, regex-lookarounds

I want to know if I can highlight strings between {**any string**}

Here is what I have tried.

```
^{(.*)}$
```

This works, but this case retrieve the paranthesis also

> **{hi}**

But the I want to retrieve only the string, not the parenthesis.

> {**hi**}

**Example:**

hell(?=o) try this syntax, it will match exactly the hell word, when it is followed by "o" and not hello

Just like that, i want to match string, when it is started after open parenthesis and between close paranthesis and not the parenthesis.

Can anyone guide me, how can we ignore the Parenthesis and retrieve just the string?

As this query is involved in custom control, I need solution using Regex

**Note**

For more information see screenshots

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Expected**

[image: Expected]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: @PedroLobito updated my requirements. Please let me know, if it helps you

Comment: You are asking about how to make an online regex tester work as expected. It's a wrong approach - use your regex inside code, and then ask a question. Note you already are using a capturing group - it is enough, just use `Match.Groups[1].Value` in C#. Or if you replace just use `$1`. Without your C# code, the question is unclear.

Comment: by highlight you mean `<b>word</b>` ?

Comment: guys, i used online regex tester for better explanation.

Example:

hell(?=o)

try this syntax, it will match exactly the hell word, when it is followed by "o". Just like that, i want to match string, when it is started after open parenthesis and between close paranthesis.

Comment: @PedroLobito and wiktor: Do you guys understand my requirement?

Comment: I only know that you want to highlight the regex match, but highlight how and where? using a `css` class, a html `tag`, like `<b>`?

Comment: @PedroLobito: no, see my above comments and i have updated my question clearly. Hope it helps.

Comment: No, it didn't help me. GL

Comment: I think the OP's specifically means 'highlight' as in successfully match on the value requested. Using the Regex tester that they're using the matches are 'highlighted' when matches are made.

Comment: And there is no need to - in C#, it is enough to use `var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"{(.*?)}").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

`(?<={)(.*)(?=})`

See my example on [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%7B%29%28.*%29%28%3F%3D%7D%29&i=%7Bhello%20world%7D%20this%20will%20be%20mached%20correctly)

Make sure to check this post about Lookahed and Lookbacks. [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason you cannot use groups - in your example you already use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Just finish the pattern by also adding a lookbehind to the start of the pattern.

```
(?<={)[^}]*(?=})
```

`[^}]*` matches [any amount](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) of characters, [that are not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `}` if preceded by `{` if followed by `}`.

[See demo at Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%7B%29%5B%5E%7D%5D*%28%3F%3D%7D%29&i=%7Bhi%7D)

Comment: Just one thing - `[^}]` matches newline as well, and OP *may* not want that.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that you specifically want to retrieve the values between the curly braces (not parenthesis), you will need to perform the Regex match - that groups.

```
string phrase = "{hi} my name is Chris.";    
Regex exp = new Regex(@"\{(.*?)\}");
string match = exp.Match("{hi}").Groups[1].Value;
```

Now, I will admit that this isn't the most intuitive method; however, it certainly gets the job done. The **Full Match** returns '*{hi}*', whereas **Group 1** returns the value you're looking for '*hi*'.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if I can highlight strings between {any string}

In the realm of regular expressions there is a difference between a **match** and a **capture** and basic **grouping**.

You want to match `{hi}` but you want to get `hi` into a *capture* Group. That is done using the `( )` construct pattern. A match can hold all three of those in different groups.

Keep these items in mind.

- `Groups[0]` is **always** the **whole match**
- `Groups[1-N]` are individual captures when `( )` construct is specified.
- The pattern `{Hi}` will match "{Hi}" which can be found in the whole match of `Group[0]`.
- The pattern `{(Hi)}` will also match "{Hi}" in `Group[0]`, but it will capture "hi" into `Group[1]`.

---

I can't speak to the process of highlighting of text in winforms.